# Can we delete rows in PostgreSQL and cascade the deletion to all related rows in different tables where a Ref ID/ Foreign key constraint is utilized?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I perform row deletions in PostgreSQL with cascading effects on all related rows in different tables, utilizing Ref IDs or Foreign Key constraints?
If possible, I want to use this functionality in pgadmin4 GUI.

When I try to delete a row it gives following error,
`SQL Error [23503]: ERROR: update or delete on table "tbl_xyz" violates foreign key constraint "tbl_abc_id_2b79de29_fk_tbl" on table "tbl_abc" Detail: Key (id)=(110) is still referenced from table "tbl_abc".`

Comment: That's why you use foreign keys, just use the settings that works best for you: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK

Comment: We can truncate tables, But can we do same in case of rows?

Comment: Sure, just give it a try. By the way, this has nothing to do with a GUI like pgadmin4, this is functionality from the database itself. For what I know, every relational database supports this.

Answer (score 2):

That is certainly possible. How PostgreSQL behaves when deleting rows depends on the properties of the foreign key. In my opinion one should always set the `ON DELETE` and `ON UPDATE` settings so user is aware of the behavior.

```sql
CREATE TABLE parent(
  id int primary key,
  info text
);

CREATE TABLE child(
  id int primary key,
  parent_id int REFERENCES parent(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  info text
);


INSERT INTO parent(id, info) VALUES
  (1, 'parent1'),
  (2, 'parent2')
;


INSERT INTO  child(id, parent_id, info) VALUES
  (1, 1, 'child1 of parent1'),
  (2, 1, 'child2 of parent1'),
  (3, 2, 'child1 of parent2'),
  (4, 2, 'child2 of parent2')
;

DELETE FROM parent WHERE id = 1;
SELECT * FROM child;

 id | parent_id |       info
----+-----------+-------------------
  3 |         2 | child1 of parent2
  4 |         2 | child2 of parent2
```

`ON DELETE` action has the following options:

| Action | description |
| --- | --- |
| NO ACTION | Prevents parent deletion if referencing objects exists. Does the checing at the commit time. (default) |
| RESTRICT | Prevents parent deletion if referencing objects exists. Does the checing right after command. |
| CASCADE | When deleting a parent also all children are deleted |
| SET NULL | When deleting a parent `parent_id` field is set to null for all referencing rows. |
| SET NULL | When deleting a parent `parent_id` field is set to default value for all referencing rows. |